# python script to key in the date range from a file and redirect the output

Tags: python

i have a input file 1.csv

```
42200000000099920160613000000 column=h:profile, timestamp=1465780825878, value=[{"weight":100.0,"centroidLatitude":23.723663502974482,"centroidLongitude":58.812344445144724,"centroidUncertainity":1.384228745747496E11,:{"Wed21":100.0,"Wed20":100.0,"Wed23":100.0,"Wed22":100.0,"Wed14":100.0,"Wed13":100.0,"Wed16":100.0,"Wed15":100.0,"Wed18":100.0,"Wed17":100.0,"Wed19":100.0
42200000000099920160613000000 column=h:profile, timestamp=1465780825878, value=[{"weight":100.0,"centroidLatitude":23.723663502974482,"centroidLongitude":58.812344445144724,"centroidUncertainity":1.384228745747496E11,:{"Wed21":100.0,"Wed20":100.0,"Wed23":100.0,"Wed22":100.0,"Wed14":100.0,"Wed13":100.0,"Wed16":100.0,"Wed15":100.0,"Wed18":100.0,"Wed17":100.0,"Wed19":100.0
42200000000099920160614000000 column=h:profile, timestamp=1465780825878, value=[{"weight":100.0,"centroidLatitude":23.723663502974482,"centroidLongitude":58.812344445144724,"centroidUncertainity":1.384228745747496E11,:{"Wed21":100.0,"Wed20":100.0,"Wed23":100.0,"Wed22":100.0,"Wed14":100.0,"Wed13":100.0,"Wed16":100.0,"Wed15":100.0,"Wed18":100.0,"Wed17":100.0,"Wed19":100.0,
42200000000099920160615000000 column=h:profile, timestamp=1465780825878, value=[{"weight":100.0,"centroidLatitude":23.723663502974482,"centroidLongitude":58.812344445144724,"centroidUncertainity":1.384228745747496E11,:{"Wed21":100.0,"Wed20":100.0,"Wed23":100.0,"Wed22":100.0,"Wed14":100.0,"Wed13":100.0,"Wed16":100.0,"Wed15":100.0,"Wed18":100.0,"Wed17":100.0,"Wed19":100.0
```

i want to get the records only from 20160613 to 20160614.

The program i have written , i need to enter the start date and end date in the code, instead of that i should ask the user to enter the start date and end date and redirect the output to a file

```
import re
import datetime

# please input from console i have used fixed values
lbound_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("20160613", "%Y%m%d")
rbound_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("20160614", "%Y%m%d")


t= open("1.csv")
p = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{15}(?P<date>[0-9]{8})')

out = []


for line in t:
    s = p.match(line)
if s:
    sdate_str = s.group("date")
    # sort the dates to get only ones between range
    sdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sdate_str, "%Y%m%d")
    if sdate >= lbound_date and sdate <= rbound_date:
        out.append(line)


for lineout in out:
    print (lineout)
```

Comment: if the indentation is like in your program, no wonder why it doesn't work. `if s` shoudl be in your loop.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: in my script i want the script to ask,  for eg please enter the start date: and please enter the end date: and the output should redirect to a new file

Comment: @jean could you please correct where the indentation is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is wrong so your loop does nothing useful. Only last line is processed in the end (`s` is the match for the last line):

fix: indent properly from 2nd line:

```
for line in t:
    s = p.match(line)
    if s:
        sdate_str = s.group("date")
        # sort the dates to get only ones between range
        sdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sdate_str, "%Y%m%d")
        if sdate >= lbound_date and sdate <= rbound_date:
            out.append(line)
```

(sorry for such a trivial answer)

Comment: Thanks for correcting it.. now my question is  i don't want to give these dates in the script                                                                           lbound_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("20160613", "%Y%m%d")
rbound_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("20160614", "%Y%m%d")                 i want the script  to ask the lbound date and rbound date

Comment: in python 3, use `date = input("enter start date")` to prompt for a date. Use `raw_input` in python 2.